# Fast searching of Point2f vector in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `Point2F` vector, `std::vector<Point2F> vxy;`. The length is 70000 in rows.
I have another `Point2F` variable as `Point2F var;`. I like to implement fast searching for `var` in the `vxy verctor` and return is the matched index of the vector. I consider `std::lower_bound`, but it is only for normal data type like int. How to implement like that searching algorithm for Point2F type?
Thanks

Comment: For most ordered datatypes or searches in the standard library you just need to implement the `<` operator on your class.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `operator ==` overloaded in the `Point2F`, you can use `std::find` algorithm.

```
std::vector<Point2F>::iterator it = std::find(vxy.begin(), vxy.end(), var);

if (it != vxy.end())
{
   int index;
   index = it - vxy.begin();
}
```